# how do I find references to IDs/records that no longer exist

Tags: mysql

Say I have record customers and record transactions.  Each transaction has a customer ID field pointing to the customer record.

Obviously if you delete a customer record, you have to delete all the transactions first, to avoid dangling pointers, IDs for which the corresponding record no longer exists. But I inherited this database and I want to make sure that there were no past coding errors leaving inconsistencies in the DB.

If I want to verify that there are no dangling pointers (no customer_id values for which customers.id does not exist), what kind of query would I use?

Comment: A `LEFT JOIN` query. Google that, have a try. You might also want to have a look at foreign keys and their `DELETE CASCADE` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Customer_id FROM TRANSACTION TRX
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Customer WHERE CustomerId = TRX.Customer_Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply:

```
SELECT record_id FROM records_table WHERE customer_id NOT IN (SELECT customer_id FROM customer_table);
```

This will show you every record associated with a customer_id which does not exist in the customers table.

And then to remove:

```
DELETE FROM records_table WHERE customer_id NOT IN (SELECT customer_id FROM customer_table);
```